# mySQL Auto Increment Duplicate entry '4294967295'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the table of users.

I tried to insert two rows into the empty users table
**(not the table with existing rows**).

While inserting the data,it inserted the first data's **id (primary key int(10) unsigned autoincrement)** as **4294967295** .While inserting second data,it caused the **Integrity Constraint : Duplicate entry '4294967295'** since its not possible to insert the value greater than 4294967295.

I tried dropping the table and created again(**Though its not the right way)**, it worked fine.

I need to know **Why it happened??** and solution for this.

Comment: Do you have 4294967295 entries or are there fewer so when you created the new table it gave them all new `id`s?

Comment: I don't know why this question is downvoted. It's actually valid, and for someone not familiar with size of integer or for someone who isn't a developer with some experience - this one is tough to crack. Please don't be dicks when downvoting. I hope you got your solution. Basically, you exceeded the available numbers. You must alter your table and make your column a `bigint`.

Comment: No FYI I know the ranges for the data types.. I inserted the rows for the very first time..practically the ids should be 1 and 2 for that rows..

Comment: There is a function for this, updated my anser

Comment: Something went wrong with creating tables then. You exceeded the numbers. Can you include your migrations as well? Do you know how to administer MySQL? You can use PHPMyAdmin or similar tools (if you don't know how to use mysql terminal) to check what the auto_increment is set to start at.

Comment: Yeah I know.. It autoincrement was set to one only..i checked migrations as well.. It is increment('id') as per laravel

Answer (score 4):

Integer has 32 Bit so your max value is

```
2^32 = 4294967295
```

So if you need more you need another type like bigint.

```
$this->bigIncrements('id');
```

Will use bigint as increment.

Answer (score 3):

```
id (primary key BIGINT(10) unsigned autoincrement)
```

Int range is -2^32 to 2^32.
So if you need greater values than int=2^32 you can use bigint that range is -2^64 to 2^64.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please? It's correct, but the reason *why* isn't included.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting into a table with an auto increment field, the auto increment field itself should not be specified at all. like in the example categorieID is the primary key

```
Query("INSERT INTO prod_categorie (categorieID, parentID) VALUES (?, ?)", array($chkParent, $txtParentCategorie));
```

Should be just

```
Query("INSERT INTO prod_categorie (parentID) VALUES (?)", array($txtParentCategorie));
```

Comment: No I am not specifying auto increment field

Comment: Still I didn't get the answer for this question .

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the auto_increment value has reach its maximum value.

It could either because you  have too many records, or because you made a mistake.

This usually happens when  you accidentally insert a new record a provide the auto_increment value.

Most of the time that's because you have a column with a similar name and you make a typo that leads to the auto_increment value updated with the one you provided, which is 4294967295 if you provided a string instead of an int.

To solve this:

- delete the record whose PK value is  4294967295,
- check what was the max increment value by running

> ```
> select max(autoincrementColumNameHere) from tableNameHere
> ```

- update your AUTO_INCREMENT value by running

> ```
>  ALTER TABLE tableNameHere AUTO_INCREMENT = (maxValue+1)
> ```